# Memory leak in the empty Activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I recently decided to use [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) in my projects, So I created a project with an empty `Activity` just for test, When I run the app (just after project creation with no logic code or views) I got memory leak log from this library:

```
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * com.example.leaktest.MainActivity has leaked:
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT static android.app.ActivityThread.sCurrentActivityThread
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * references android.app.ActivityThread.mActivities
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * references android.util.ArrayMap.mArray
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * references array java.lang.Object[].[1]
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * references android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.example.leaktest.MainActivity instance
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * Retaining: 1.7KB.
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: 9180226a-8a65-4c94-9d12-4562a6d88157
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * Device: Genymotion generic genymotion_vbox86tp_5.1_150409_105318 vbox86tp
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * Android Version: 5.1 API: 22 LeakCanary: 1.4-beta2 3799172
07-20 04:32:36.742 2967-4915/com.example.leaktest D/LeakCanary: * Durations: watch=5808ms, gc=158ms, heap dump=1953ms, analysis=15795ms
```

**App** class:

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this);
    }

    public static RefWatcher getRefWatcher(Context context) {
        App application = (App) context.getApplicationContext();
        return application.refWatcher;
    }

    private RefWatcher refWatcher;
}
```

**MainActivity** class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        App.getRefWatcher(this).watch(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I will appreciate if someone explain it to me.

Comment: without any code it's hard to say what is going on here... are you sure that you have not added any code on that you have setup leak canary properly?

Comment: Hi @sockeqwe, As I mentioned there's no code, just a blank activity with no view in layout file.

Comment: No Fragments or other stuff? Do you setup leakcanary in `Application.onCreate()` as described in the docs or do you do something in your MainActivity?

Comment: @sockeqwe nothing at all ! I posted my code.

Comment: Seems `android.app.ActivityThread.sCurrentActivityThread` keeps a static reference to `MainActivity` (if I mistake not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RefWatcher` should be in the `onDestroy()` method, not `onCreate()` (see a similar [reported issue here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/45)).

You don't even need to do this, since LeakCanary watches `Activity` references automatically. From the [FAQ](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ):

> LeakCanary.install() returns a pre configured RefWatcher. It also installs an ActivityRefWatcher that automatically detects if an activity is leaking after Activity.onDestroy() has been called.

Comment: Shall I receive a log informing me there is no leak ?

Comment: Not sure, honestly.

Comment: You're right about the `Refwatcher` scope,I don't receive any leak log

Comment: Not sure but I think library should give a "No leak" log now, let me create a leak and test your answer, thanks by the way

Comment: Well I ran the test, No LEAK THEN No LOG, Apparently logs will show up when a memory leak occurs, Also as you said `LeakCanary.install` is enough, Thanks bro +1.