# Android leak canary - leaking empty activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm getting notification as my activities are being leaked, even though activities are all empty.

here is the trace:

```
    ApplicationLeak(className=com.bcx.tracker.ui.login.LoginActivity, leakTrace=
    ┬
    ├─ android.app.Activity$1
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Anonymous subclass of android.app.IRequestFinishCallback$Stub
    │    GC Root: Global variable in native code
    │    ↓ Activity$1.this$0
    │                 ~~~~~~
    ╰→ com.bcx.tracker.ui.login.LoginActivity
    ​     Leaking: YES (Activity#mDestroyed is true and ObjectWatcher was watching this)
    ​     key = fc3d8e13-c51c-4ff8-995f-4e0da90f085b
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 7889
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 2886
    ​     key = b809b94b-fd3c-4d26-bda4-7f175624c3c3
    , retainedHeapByteSize=166095)
```

I just added the dependency in `build.gradle`

```
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-beta-3'
```

Is there anything that I'm missing here?.

i've gone through [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470388/memory-leak-in-the-empty-activity) which didn't help.

My device:

OnePlus 7, android 10

Emulator , android 10

Comment: What do you mean when you say even though all my activities are all empty? The best rule to avoid memory leak is to avoid holding instance of your activity or fragment in your other classes. Your classes should know nothing about your view elements. Instead, your activity or fragment should ask it's presenter for anything it needs to function as desired.

Comment: It's an  app with no extra code at all. I just made two activities with default basic template and haven't hold any instances anywhere.

Comment: It is still leaking in OnePlus 7T, I think this is a bug on Oxygen OS.

Comment: I got the same issue Samsung m01 android 10, did you get a solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a known leak in the Android Framework in Android 10: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139738913

Comment: in this link issue status is fixed, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to finish your root activity while your Android is Q, unfortunately this will leak your memory as this twitter [thread](https://twitter.com/Piwai/status/1169274624749658112) says

> Leak introduced when adding support for Bubbles (as chathead activities). Properly reported but: "We've deferred this issue for consideration in a future release."
>
> This leak is happening because IRequestFinishCallback$Stub is an IPC callback that ends up being held by the activity manager process

The workaround to this issue as stated

> You can "fix" this leak by overriding Activity.onBackPressed() and calling Activity.finishAfterTransition(); instead of super if the activity is task root and the fragment stack is empty.

Here is the full suggested code to add also to check the part of being root activity and fragment stack is empty

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q &&
        isTaskRoot &&
        supportFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment?.childFragmentManager?.backStackEntryCount ?: 0 == 0 &&
        supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0
    ) {
        finishAfterTransition()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Tested on Mi A2 - Android Q (android one)

You can also track the issue updates from google issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139738913)